# WPF Changing image path and show the new image in Runtime

Tags: wpf, image, bitmapimage, imagesource

I have WPF Image, the source of it is local image URI on my Hard Disk, and I'm using converter to load it.

I want to alter the image on the hard disk ( replace it with another one )
and in **runtime** show the new image

Here the XAML of the image

```
 <Image  Stretch="Fill">
                                            <Image.Style>
                                                <Style TargetType="Image">
                                                    <Setter Property="Source" Value="{Binding ImagePath,Converter={StaticResource ImageFileLoader},UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
                                                </Style>
                                            </Image.Style>
                                        </Image>
```

Here is the converter

```
 class ImageFileLoader : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        if (value != null)
        {
            string filePath = value.ToString();
            if (File.Exists(filePath))
            {
                BitmapImage result = new BitmapImage();
                result.BeginInit();
                result.UriSource = new Uri(filePath);
                result.CacheOption = BitmapCacheOption.OnLoad;
                result.EndInit();
                return result;
            }

        }

        return null;
    }
```

}

Note : I tried to change the `CacheOption` in the converter to `BitmapCacheOption.None` or any other option ... it did't work because in this case I cannot alter the image on the Hard disk

Comment: @Clemens no it does not implement it, however it do respond to the event firing PropertyChanged  when the ImagePath property has changed.

Comment: Sorry, I've misread your XAML. It's not the ImageFileLoader class that would have to implement INotifyPropertyChanged, but the class that declares the `ImagePath` property. You should perhaps post the relevant parts of that code, too.

Comment: Yes the model class that contains property  'ImagePath' implements INotifyPropertyChanged Interface ... and it's simple class you can imagine it like it just has the ImagePath  property

Comment: Is there any specific reason to set the `Source` binding of the Image control in a Style Setter? You could have done it directly at the Image declaration, like `<Image Source="{Binding ...}"/>`. Is the Source property possibly also being set anywhere else, and hence the binding gets overwritten?

Comment: No, there is no specific reason for that, and the Source property is not being changed any where, I just want to change the file manually and have the changing showed on the screen

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When the Framework loads an `Image`, it puts an annoying hold on it, so that if you try to delete or move the actual image file, you'll  get an `Exception` saying something like *Cannot access the file because it is being used*. To get around that, I created an `IValueConverter` like yours in order to set the `Image.CacheOption` to `BitmapCacheOption.OnLoad` which *Caches the entire image into memory at load time*, thereby removing the hold.

However, the code in my Converter looks similar to yours, so I'm not sure why it won't work for you. Here is what my `IValueConverter` code looks like:

```
using (FileStream stream = File.OpenRead(filePath))
{
    image.BeginInit();
    image.StreamSource = stream;
    image.CacheOption = BitmapCacheOption.OnLoad;
    image.EndInit();
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply 
My problem is NOT that I cannot change the image file manually, I do can change the file ( rename it or even delete it )

The main problem is that the alteration is not being showed on the UI

Comment: Make sure that you have implemented the `INotifyPropertyChangedInterface` on your `ImagePath` property. If that doesn't help, you may also need to set your file path property to an empty string first (to clear the old path) and then set it to the new value.

Comment: thank you ... the whole problem was some wrong value set to the imagPath

Comment: Changing image.UriSource to image.StreamSource and feeding it a Filestream instead of the file path did the trick for me! thx